# Explore a bouncy castle store object

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

My question is strictly related to [Bouncy Castle i cannot get all certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202771/bouncy-castle-i-cannot-get-all-certificate).

I use the BC code https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html whith some little variation.

```
  Store                   certStore = s.getCertificates();
  SignerInformationStore  signers = s.getSignerInfos();
  Collection              c = signers.getSigners();
  Iterator                it = c.iterator();

  while (it.hasNext())
  {
      SignerInformation   signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
      Collection          certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());

      Iterator              certIt = certCollection.iterator();
      X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();

      if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert)))
      {
          verified++;
      }   
  }
```

My purpose is to extract all certificate(signers + them issuers) from the "certStore" , and verify them against a specicific keystore.

But to extract a certificate form certStore, there is only "certStore.getMatches".

The signers extract obviously only the signers and used in "certStore.getMatches" extract only the certificate of the signer(one or more).

I have to control each certificate, his CRL his date, not only the signer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step to obtain allcertificate is to use a null selector

```
 ArrayList<X509CertificateHolder> listCertDatFirm = new ArrayList(store.getMatches(null));
```

Then you have a group of certificate; looping recoursively you can rebuild the correct chain.